# When are per-user temp files in /var/folders/ removed?

Tags: macos, filesystem

How often and under what conditions are files under `var/folders/` removed?

If an application creates a file under `var/folders/`, is it possible for that file to be removed by the system before the application quits?

---

Here's a related question, but it's 10 years old and refers to `/tmp` and not `var/folders`: https://superuser.com/questions/187071/in-macos-how-often-is-tmp-deleted

Comment: What's the difference between `/tmp` and `/var/...` temporaries?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the type of files created:

For files that the application has created as temporary files, they're up for removal when they have not been accessed for 3 days.

For files that the application has created as cache files, they're not normally automatically removed. Instead they can be removed when performing a safe boot (hold down the shift key while booting your Mac).

And no, as long as the application keeps the create file open (i.e. it has a reference to the file descriptor), it should never be the case that the  file is removed from the file system before the application quits.

Note that application can and do work with files that are not visible for a regular user. I.e. if your application opens a file and keeps it open, the user can delete the file and it will disappear from directory listings - however the file is still there and the contents can be accessed by the application without problems. When the application closes the file (or the application is closed) - the file is permanently deleted from the file system.

As mentioned in the comment (oct. 16th, 2020) the above is documented in the manual page for `confstr`. Just run `man confstr` in the Terminal to view the manual page.

Comment: I did come across a comment stating that temp files can be removed when they have not been accessed for 3 days. Unfortunately, the most concrete reference to this bit of info was a community article from 6 years ago. Do you happen to have a link to any official documentation on the matter? (for that point or the others)

Comment: Yes, Apple lists this fact (and the others) in the manual page for confstr. Just run “man confstr” in the Terminal.

Comment: I don't see anything about this in the man page for confstr. Perhaps it was in a previous version?

Comment: I looked up it on macOS Catalina, which is the latest operating system (Big Sure is still in Beta)... just checked again, and it's there! For example it says "By default, files in this location may be cleaned (removed) by the system if they are not accessed in 3 days."

Comment: Whats is the difference between a regular file and a cache file? Are there cache files also in the /var/folders/... directory hierarchy?

Comment: If you look only at the file itself in the file system, there's no technical difference. The difference is the meaning applied to it by the application. I.e. a "regular file" usually holds some kind of data that the user wants to keep around until further notice, a "cache file" is usually some data that the user wants to keep around for a short period of time but which can be deleted if space is needed for other things, as it can be created again from scratch. Similarly a "temp file" is typically only needed for a short period of time and you would prefer it deleted when no longer used.

Comment: @Arne Yes, there are cache files in that hierarchy as well. If look at the folder structure, you'll notice that each folder is subdivided into a "T" and "C" subfolder - which stands for "temporary" and "cache". So the cache files are in the "C" subfolder.

Answer (score 4):

`man confstr` is the official documentation about the /var/folders/ temporary directory (**EDIT: "un-accessed"**) contents being deleted by the system after 3 days. and the /var/folders/ cache directory contents won't get deleted by the system.

```
% man confstr
 ...
 _CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR
         Provides the path to a user's temporary items directory. The directory will be created it if does
         not already exist. This directory is created with access permissions of 0700 and restricted by the
         umask(2) of the calling process and is a good location for temporary files.

         By default, files in this location may be cleaned (removed) by the system if they are not accessed
         in 3 days.

 _CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR
         Provides the path to the user's cache directory. The directory will be created if it does not
         already exist. This directory is created with access permissions of 0700 and restricted by the
         umask(2) of the calling process and is a good location for user cache data as it will not be
         automatically cleaned by the system.

         Files in this location will be removed during safe boot.
 ...
% getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR
/var/folders/xx/xxxx_xxxx/T/
% getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR
/var/folders/xx/xxxx_xxxx/C/
```

Comment: My answer from 2020 already includes the information from confstr. Note that it is not after "3 days" - but rather after a minimum of 3 days where the file has not been acceessed - so files can live on very long. My answer includes a way you can indicate to the system that you want these folders cleaned up.